# Difference between Schengen Visa and an EU Dependant visa

Tags: schengen

I want to know the difference between a Schengen Visa for a non-EEA spouse and the EU Dependant visa for a non-EEA spouse. I know the EU Dependant visa is free and  the EU spouse needs to be accompanying, but is there any difference in the visa stamp or visa type on the passport or the duration for which they are issued?

Comment: Where have you found this terminology?

Comment: Yes, please add links.

Comment: Do you want us to Google it for you? Have you looked up 'EU Family Permit'?  Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I am quite aware of what the 'EU Family Permit' is but what I want to know is it a different type of a visa and is there a difference on the visa sticker on the passport.

Comment: Is there a difference in the passport sticker between a Schengen Visa and a EU Family Permit and do they have different conditions of stay in the EU countries

Comment: Why do you care what the visa sticker looks like?

Comment: Is there a difference in the Visa Type, ie. Schengen visa which has a fee and the EU Dependant visa which is free.